# extract characters from the variable

Tags: r

I have two variables a and b in dataset la

```
a                                b
dflsfufdsbhfsdjklfhsajkdfksf     5
sdnfsdhfuisdflkjsdnjkfksflsdfk   8
```

I want to create a new variable c such that i want to extract characters from the varaibles a from position( value of varaible b) to 8 characters.

below is the desired output

```
c
fufdsbhf
fuisdflk
```

I have used below code.

```
la$c[i1] <-substr(la$a[i1],la$b[i1],8)
```

but above giving be below results

```
c
fufd
f
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `la$c[i1] <-substr(la$a[i1],la$b[i1],la$b[i1]+8)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stop` option in `substr` defines at which character in a character vector to stop, not how many characters to take after the `start`.

So this should do it:

```
la$c[i] <- substr(la$a[i], la$b[i], la$b[i]+7)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it,

```
df$c <- substr(df$a, df$b, df$b+7)
df$c
#[1] "fufdsbhf" "fuisdflk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `loop`, you can you use `apply` function for a `dataframe`

```
ab$c <- sapply(ab, function(x){substr(x,ab$b,ab$b+7)})
```